# Django User Registration - not sure what is going wrong

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views, django-authentication

Very, very new to Django. I'm attempting to create a user registration process with custom form inputs. However, I have a few issues with the general persisting of new users to the database. This is what I have defined in my forms.py:

```
class UserRegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    required_css_class = 'required'
    email = forms.EmailField()
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserRegistrationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['username'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Username'})
        self.fields['username'].required = True
        self.fields['username'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your username'}

        self.fields['email'].widget = EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Email'})
        self.fields['email'].required = True
        self.fields['email'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your email'}

        self.fields['first_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Forename'})
        self.fields['first_name'].required = True
        self.fields['first_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your first_name'}

        self.fields['last_name'].widget = TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Surname'})
        self.fields['last_name'].required = True
        self.fields['last_name'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your last_name'}

        self.fields['password1'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Password'})
        self.fields['password1'].required = True
        self.fields['password1'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please enter your Password'}

        self.fields['password2'].widget = PasswordInput(attrs={'placeholder': 'Confirm password'})
        self.fields['password2'].required = True
        self.fields['password2'].error_messages = {'required': 'Please confirm your Password'}
```

I also have the following in my views.py file:

```
class UserRegistrationView(FormView):
    disallowed_url = ''
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    success_url = '/blog'
    template_name = 'oauth/user/registration_form.html'

    def registration_allowed(self):
        return getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_OPEN', True)

    def register(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
                new_user.save()

                return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', { 'new_user': new_user })
        else:
            return render(request, 'oauth/user/registration_form.html', { 'form': form })

    def get_success_url(self, user=None):
        return super(UserRegistrationView, self).get_success_url()
```

What's worrying:

1. It doesn't create a new user in the database to be logged in (should I expect to be able to see the newly created user in the general admin dashboard?)
2. It is able to sign in with the superuser! (I really don't get that one bit, like, seriously couldn't write that if I tried!)

Any help in where I may have gone wrong would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing class based and function based views. Class based views don't have a method called "register"; yours will never be called.

Actually the method you have written is a complete function based view in its own right. Extract it from the class, remove the `self` parameter, and change the urlconf to call the function directly, and it should work.

Comment: What method could I call to keep it a class based view? Are there any examples of class based register views you know of?

Comment: Many. But first you have to understand how class based views work, either from the docs or something like ccbv.co.uk. For example, most of the code in that register method is irrelevant, because the view does it for you; except the actual user creation, which would go in `form_valid`.

Comment: Hmmm, ccbv.co.uk doesn't contain any examples of class based User Registration views as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `post` method (or change the name of `register` to `post`) and add it to your class so that `as_view()` knows what to do with your class. then add it to your urlconf as a view.

```
class UserRegistrationView(FormView):
    disallowed_url = ''
    form_class = UserRegistrationForm
    success_url = '/blog'
    template_name = 'oauth/user/registration_form.html'

    def post(self, request, *arg, **kwargs):
        return self.register(request)

    def registration_allowed(self):
        return getattr(settings, 'REGISTRATION_OPEN', True)

    def register(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = UserRegistrationForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                new_user = form.save(commit=False)
                new_user.set_password(form.cleaned_data['password1'])
                new_user.save()

                return render(request, 'blog/post/list.html', {'new_user': new_user})
        else:
            return render(request, 'oauth/user/registration_form.html', {'form': form})

    def get_success_url(self, user=None):
        return super(UserRegistrationView, self).get_success_url()
```

Then, in your `urls`:

```
urlpatterns = [
        # . . . 
        url(r'^register_user/$', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name='register_user'),
        # . . . 
]
```

You could also add a `get` method and use it to render your form if you are interested in keeping all of your form logic contained to one view class.